# i want to install my sql client and server

Tags: server, 13.10, mysql, client

i need to form network like "*directory service*"
i am using ubuntu 13.10 client and 13.10 server i need to install "***my sql server and client***" 
Thanks and regards 
in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

Just open your terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and paste the above code in that.